# Callback event to display a progress or to cancel an Amazon S3 upload using CloudAPI in C++Builder

Tags: delphi, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, c++builder, vcl

I would like to know if there is a way to have a callback event or some similar mechanism to display a progress of an upload to Amazon S3 service, using the CloudAPI classes included in C++Builder XE5.

I haven't seen anything related to this on the documentation or the classes themselves.

I'm using TAmazonStorageService.UploadObject.

Apart from the User-Interface progress, some kind of callback is needed in case you need to gracefully abort the process. As is you can only expect for the function to finish and delete the object, in case it was correctly uploaded and the process should be cancelled.

Comment: Are you using this method? http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Data.Cloud.AmazonAPI.TAmazonStorageService.UploadObject I haven't worked with CloudAPI, but it's strange you need to have the data in a byte array! If it were working with a TStream, you could pass it an intermediate TStream and make that fire progress events.

Comment: @StijnSanders Yes, I'm using that method. I don't know if there is another way, as you say, to use a TStream instead. From what I can see in the class that is the only possible way. I tried an "intermediate" approach using multi part uploads (that way at least I can have more granularity and can upadte the progress for each part) but there I find some socket errors I haven't been able to overcome.